# CdkPipeline - Manual S3 Artifact Bucket/Role Assignment Failing

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, aws-cdk

I am working on a simple CDK Pipeline deployment based on the CDK Workshop example here: https://cdkworkshop.com/20-typescript/70-advanced-topics/200-pipelines/4000-build-stage.html.  The base project builds without issue and I have successfully ported our own stack code over to the project, disabled KMS by setting crossAccountKeys to false.  To keep pipeline resources more manageable I tried to manually assign a shared S3 artifact bucket to the pipeline.  This yields the following error:

Insufficient permissions - The service role or action role doesn’t have the permissions required to access the Amazon S3 bucket named cdktestbucketforpipeline. Update the IAM role permissions, and then try again. Error: Amazon S3:AccessDenied:Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403…

The shared bucket has a policy allowing all services access.
To get around this error I tried to manually assign a role to the pipeline.  Initially I created a restricted role, then assigned Admin permissions and then Power User.  I had read somewhere that an Admin role cannot assume roles because it is Admin.  With each of these assignments I receive the following error:

arn:aws:iam:: 012345678910:role/PipelineDeployingLambdaStack-PipelineRoleB27FAA37-1FWCSUUPOC8T8 is not authorized to perform AssumeRole on role arn:aws:iam:: 012345678910:role/PipelineDeployingLambdaSt-PipelineAssetsFileRole59-DBZ4RKIOSURN

For context, here is the code excerpt, after the PipelineStack class, where I added the bucket and role:

```
// The basic pipeline declaration. This sets the initial structure
    // of our pipeline
    const pipeline = new CdkPipeline(this, 'Pipeline', {
        pipelineName: 'WorkshopPipeline',
        cloudAssemblyArtifact,

        crossAccountKeys: false,
        // Generates the source artifact from the repo we created in the last step
        sourceAction: new codepipeline_actions.CodeCommitSourceAction({
            actionName: 'CodeCommit', // Any Git-based source control
            output: sourceArtifact, // Indicates where the artifact is stored
            repository: repo // Designates the repo to draw code from
        }),

        // Builds our source code outlined above into a could assembly artifact
        synthAction: SimpleSynthAction.standardNpmSynth({
            sourceArtifact: sourceArtifact, // Where to get source code to build
            cloudAssemblyArtifact: cloudAssemblyArtifact, // Where to place built source

            buildCommand: 'npm run build', // Language-specific build cmd
            environment : {
              buildImage: LinuxBuildImage.STANDARD_4_0,
              privileged: true
            }
        })
    });
pipeline.codePipeline.artifactBucket = Bucket.fromBucketName(this, 'S3ArtifactBucket', 'cdktestbucketforpipeline');
pipeline.codePipeline.role = Role.fromRoleArn(this, 'CDKS3TestRole', 'arn:aws:iam::012345678910:role/CDKS3Test');
const deploy = new WorkshopPipelineStage(this, 'Deploy');
pipeline.addApplicationStage(deploy);
```